# Get Visual Studio Test to work on a Jenkins server

Tags: visual-studio, jenkins, sdk

I have a Jenkins server setup to build a mixed C++/C# application. I've got Visual Studio Test Agent 2017 and Visual Studio Build Tools 2017 installed but I can't build the Visual Studio test projects. The error I get is:

```
error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'VisualStudio' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft'
```

It looks as though the appropriate assemblies are not available.

I'm using this SDK to install tools for Visual Studio 2015 which is possible with the 2017 SDK and that part works fine - I can build VS 2015 projects. Except for test projects.

Is there some extra package I need to install in order to make this work? My alternative is to install NUnit but that means rewriting the unit tests.

Comment: I've found MSTEST on my server but not on the path, and I've found Microsoft.VisualStudio assemblies but MSBUILD isn't seeing them.

Comment: I created a small application and copied it to my Jenkins server; I added via NuGet MSTest.TestAdapter and MSTest.TestFramework. On my main machine I can run MSTest and see the test run. On the Jenkins machine, it simply says "No tests to execute"

Comment: Have you installed MSBuild through Build Tools 2017 Installer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to use NUnit, since I was unable to find the right SDK to install VS Test without Visual Studio itself.

NUnit required changes to Resharper, file handling and changing the attributes on the test.